# What's the best way to iterate over an array and modify the elements in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, iteration

I know Ruby has a `map!` method which do this. In PowerShell currently what I did is:

```
$new_array = @();
$array | % {
    $new_array += <do something with the currently element $)>;
}
$array = $new_array;
```

I want to know the best way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest I can think of is

```
$array | %{ $_ + 1 }
```

`$_ + 1` being the transformation I want.

So you can do:

```
$new = $array | %{$_ + 1}
```

or

```
$array = $array | %{ $_ + 1}
```

---

PS:
You can define a map function if you want:

```
function map ([scriptblock]$script, [array] $a) {

    $a | %{ & $script $_ }

}

map {param($i) $i + 1} 1,2,3
```

Or write an extension method on System.Array: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/09/06/hate-add-member-powershell-s-adaptive-type-system.aspx

Comment: Also `$anonymousFunc = { $_ * 3 }` and `1,2,3 | % $anonymousFunc`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a filter:

```
$arr = 1,2,3

 filter addone {$_ +1}
 $arr | addone
```

Or a filtering function:

```
function addone {process{$_ +1}}
$arr | addone
```

Or an anonymous filter:

```
$addone = {$_ +1}
$addone.isfilter = $true
$arr | &$addone
```

Edit:  The days of that anonymous filter working may be numbered. In the V3 beta that doesn't work any more, and I suspect that's not going to change.  It appears the script blocks are compiled as soon as they are created, and the .isfilter property can't be changed after they're compiled.